# Error on running maven project :Cannot load configuration class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I need help in resolving the below error that is coming on running maven project.
I am using **java 8, maven 3.8.1 and STS Version: 4.11.0.RELEASE**.
I am able to maven clean and maven install successfully, but getting error on running the project on local **MacOS Big Sur**.
Do I need to change maven version or cglib library version?
Please help me out.

Edit 1 : [image]
Added screenshot of java version being used.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.abc.targeting.main.capi.main(CAPI.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @50313382
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @50313382
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
2021-08-09 16:36:52.000  INFO m-c02fca9hmd6n --- [           main] ation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@733c423e: startup date [Mon Aug 09 16:36:51 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-08-09 16:36:52.002 ERROR m-c02fca9hmd6n --- [           main] g.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.abc.targeting.main.capi.main(CAPI.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @50313382
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @50313382
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This looks like the issue: `Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module`. The problem looks like using module-info.java ... furthermore you are not using JDK 8 to run your application... You should add more information which Spring Boot version you are using etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have added the details. Can you illustrate the problem you have mentioned.It will be really greatful.

Comment: The error message definitely does not come from an app running on JDK8. Please double check. The header bar on the console view should display the JDK install that is used when you start your app.

Comment: @MartinLippert How did you get that JDK 8 was not being used.

Comment: @Akash The was `java.base/` appearing in the logs that you posted from the running (failing) app, and that refers to the base module, which got introduced in JDK9 and beyond. This was not around in JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was,I was using JDK 1.8 and JRE 16 to run the application.
I first installed JDK 16 ,then removed JDK 16 and installed JDK 1.8 . So JDK used was 1.8 but by default the **highest version of JRE was picked**.
Please find attached images.

[image]

[image]